# Is memoir's 60-70 characters per line a good suggestion?

Tags: margins, memoir

I am reading the memoir documentation, *2.4.1 A note on the width of the typeblock*.

> Experiments have shown that the number of characters in a line of single column text on a page should be in the range 60 to 70 for ease of reading. The range may be as much as 45 to 75 characters but 66 characters is often considered to be the ideal number.

When I count the number of characters on the typical line in the memoir documentation pdf file, it is between 90 and 95, and this includes spaces.

Do I misunderstand the suggestion, or is the manual not eating its own dog food?

(My current textbook is short enough that I have the luxury of choosing margins, fonts, etc., as I wish, and not as dictated by the need to fit too much information into too much space.)

Comment: There is no hard optimum, the tolerable number of characters depends on the line spacing, font size, etc. The reasoning for shorter lines is that the reader has no issues in skipping to the start of the next line.

Comment: Many of the experiments that resulted in the reported character length of a line were carried out before computers were involved in typesetting.  At a rather early (1984) TUG meeting, Richard Southall gave a talk that mentioned this topic.  The resulting [TUGboat article](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb05-2/tb10south.pdf) includes this  statement: "Lines of text should not be longer than 10-12 words (60-72 characters)." The article is formatted according to the principles described, not the "usual" TUGboat style.  Worth reading.

Comment: The memoir manual is not meant as an example of good book design. It's a manual. Note that the statement about the number of chars per line comes from the black bible, aka the elements of typographic style by Robert Bringhurst

Comment: As @daleif said the `memoir` documentation is a manual not intended for leisure reading. If it was laid out as suggested it would be approximately a third as long again. Folk typically print on a4 or letterpaper which would result in much larger empty margins, or an increased font size to need a wider, and longer, textblock. Not good economy for the average user, In any case I prefer cats to dogs.

Comment: @Peter Wilson The memoir manual is one of the best (in content). I never printed a page from any manual. I read them on the screen. Most of them, with honorable exceptions, use the format for documents printed in B / W.

   The drawbacks are to many to be are listed here. It makes a very bad advertisement of the power  of LaTeX.

I think the community should produce guidelines on how to write a LaTeX manual plus an appropriate class to do so.

Comment: thx, everyone.   I think "manual != book" is the answer here.

Comment: @SimonDispa You don't like the appearance of manuals and say that the community should produce guidelines. If you are a member of that community perhaps you could start the conversation somewhere with your own recommendations. You might read them on your screen, others print them out on paper. --- GOM

Comment: @SimonDispa Perhaps an article in Tugboat would get a conversation started.